# Unwanted effect on a drupal7 page

Tags: css, drupal-7

I am using Bartik sub-them on Drupal7 and I am currently changing styles. What I have got is a n unwanted paralax-type of effect on the page. You can try it [here](http://henrylynx.com/home)  just scroll down and you will see how the header is left in the background while the other part of the page covers it.

What do I need to chnge in the CSS to make the header stick with the page?

Answer (score 0):

The position of the header on your CSS should be identified. Try making it static, absolute, relative or inherit. I'm sure that your problem concerns the position.

Comment: I have tried them, but that doesn't seems to be it.